# Rails under Apache and Passenger: no headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger, phusion

In an Rails app, I have a filter that checks some headers. Something like:

```
before_action :validate_consumer
...
def validate_consumer
    consumer = self.request.headers['HTTP_CONSUMER_SECRET'] == 'random_key'
    consumer || render_unauthorized("Consumer -")
end

def render_unauthorized(token="")
    self.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Token realm="Application"'
    render json: {error: "#{token} Bad credentials", error_description: "Denied"}, status: 401
end
```

this works perfect running locally (development), the header the view sends (CONSUMER_SECRET) is present in the request. But when I run in production mode, this header does not exists. I guess that this might have something related with my environment: that app runs under Apache (with Phusion+Passenger). Could it be this the problem? Anyone knows how to solve?

Comment: Try passing header as CONSUMER-SECRET instead of CONSUMER_SECRET.

Comment: @Sajin changes this, problems persists. No headers sent by my view (an ajax request) are present in the request headers from my rails app when running under Apache. In development mode, this is ok.

Comment: @Sajin it worken now, but I had to downcase it too (to Consumer-Secret).

Comment: I had a similar issue before with session_key. It worked in development environment. But in production, I had to make it session-key. That's why I suggested this. I have not worked with uppercase headers. Should I add this as an answer?